# Inside function variables to be used in includes in PHP

Tags: php

I have a function that includes another file like so

```
// some function
function SomeFunction()
{
   $someData = 'SomeData';
   include_once('some_file.php');
}

// some_file.php
<?php echo $someData; ?>
```

How would I get this to work where the include file can use the variables from the calling function? I will be using some output buffering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as `$someData` is defined in `SomeFunction()`, `some_file.php` will have access to `$someData`.

If you need access to variables outside of `SomeFunction()`, pass them as arguments to `SomeFunction()`.

Comment: Does it have to be directly related? I am using a `_include_once` which extends the input `include_once` for a directory offset.

Answer (score 0):

That's already available :)

See [include()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

Answer (score 0):

The best would be to not do use globals at all, but pass the variable as parameter:

```
function SomeFunction()
{
   $someData = 'SomeData';
   include_once('some_file.php');
   some_foo($someData);
}
```

Otherwise you risk transforming your code base in spaghetty code, at least on the long term.

Comment: I really don't want to do this. I am constructing a simple view engine.

Comment: you mean a template system like smarty, but simpler? If yes, I'd have the right solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

Seems kinda unorganized to include files in functions...what about...

```
function SomeFunction()
{
   $someData = 'SomeData';
   return $someData;
}

$data = SomeFunction();
<?php include('file.php') ?> // file.php can now use $data
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do anything.  Usage of `include()` (and it's siblings) is analogous to copy-pasting the code from the included file into the including file at the spot where include() is called.

Simple example

**test.php**

```
<?php

$foo = 'bar';

function test()
{
  $bar = 'baz';
  include 'test2.php';
}

test();
```

**test2.php**

```
<?php
echo '<pre>', print_r( get_defined_vars(), 1 ), '</pre>';
```

Again, this is analogous to the combined

```
<?php

$foo = 'bar';

function test()
{
  $bar = 'baz';
  echo '<pre>', print_r( get_defined_vars(), 1 ), '</pre>';
}

test();
```